# javaの静的解析で戻り値を取得する方法

Tags: java

お世話になります。

現在、javaの静的解析をjavaで行っており、メソッドの戻り値を取得したいと思っています。
imethodを使ってメソッド名を取得するところまではできたのですが、戻り値の取得する方法がわかりません。

例えばメソッド内に以下のように書かれていた場合、実行した時の戻り値（この場合は0）ではなく、hogeという変数名が得たいと思っています。

```java
public int hoge(){
  int hoge=0;
  return hoge
}
```

以上です。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 構文解析には何を使っていますか？JDTですか？

Comment: はい、JDTを使っています。

Comment: 「JDTでJavaのソースコード解析を行う」https://qiita.com/esplo/items/fa93ab6136e7697ed1d9 は参考になるかもしれません。ASTの構成ところで「ASTでは、Javaの各要素をASTNodeという型を継承したクラスにして格納します。たとえば、関数の定義はMethodDeclaration、return文はReturnStatementという型として格納されます。」とあります。

Answer (score 1):

## 回答

`IMethod`を使っていることから、`class`ファイルから`return`文で指定された式を取得しようとしていると推測しますが、この方法では必要な情報を取得できないと思います。
`class`ファイルに`return`文のソースコードの情報は含まれていないようです。
`javap`コマンドや16進ダンプで調べてみましたが、それらしい情報は見当たりませんでした。

## ソースコードがある場合

ASTVisitor を継承するクラスを作成し、`ReturnStatement node`を仮引数とする`visit`メソッド内で、`node.getExpression()`を使うと必要な情報を取得できます。

## 例

**静的解析対象コード**

```
public class Myclass {
    public int hoge() {
        int ret;
        return ret * 2;
    }
}
```

**取得結果**
`ret * 2`

## コードと実行結果

**コード**

```
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.NullProgressMonitor;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTParser;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTVisitor;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.CompilationUnit;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ReturnStatement;

import static org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.AST.JLS8;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String source = "public class Myclass {" +
                "   public int hoge() {\r\n" +
                "       int ret = 0;\r\n" +
                "       return ret * 2;\r\n" +
                "   }\r\n" +
                "}\r\n" +
                "";
        System.out.println (source);
        ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser (JLS8);
        parser.setSource (source.toCharArray ( ));
        CompilationUnit unit = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST (new NullProgressMonitor ( ));

        MyVisitor visitor = new MyVisitor ( );
        unit.accept (visitor);
        System.out.print ("END");
    }
}

class MyVisitor extends ASTVisitor {
    @Override
    public boolean visit(ReturnStatement node) {
        System.out.println ("node = [" + node.toString ( ) + "]");
        System.out.println ("node.getExpression () = [" + node.getExpression ().toString ( ) + "]");
        return super.visit (node);
    }
}
```

**実行結果**

```
node = [return ret * 2;
]
node.getExpression () = [ret * 2]
```